# how to handle name not found exception in application-context.xml?

Tags: spring

I am creating a spring project using Oracle and jboss server.

I have one bean in my application-context.xml.

```
   <!-- Datasource for TaskManager -->
    <jee:jndi-lookup id="tmTestDataSource" 
         jndi-name="test_datasource" expectedtype="javax.sql.DataSource"/>

    <bean id="tmTestJdbcTemplate" name="TmTestJdbcTemplate" class="org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate">
        <constructor-arg ref="tmTestDataSource" />
    </bean>
```

If the 'test_datasource' JNDI (one datasource.xml file in jboss deployment folder, which contains db credentials like url, uid, password) inside the file found deployment is successfull, but if the file is not there then the deployment is failing.

I want to handle this exception so that deployment should not fail.

how I can do this. Can anybody provide me any solution.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using dataSource args constructor, you can set it using setter method.
This way your bean will be created but its datasource will be null. So you will get NPE if you try to use it, but at least bean creation tree will not be stalled.